How do Batch export with Gimp Script-fu? (win11)
I was making some textures for minecraft (1.8.9) and I wanted to export them. I don't want to export one by one (it's 113 images or so) and I can't seem to find the script-fu code to make it work. It's a 16x16 pixel image, with no extra layers (I merged all layers in 1).
So, I searched around the internet, and I found nothing. I did find a simple code snipet of gimp --help but not even the help message opened, just Error: eval: unbound variable: gimp. Please help.
